# What to give path of file in ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two html (test1.html, test2.html) files in same directory `projects`. I want to include one html file into other.

In side test1.html, I included the following test2.html file.

**Case1:**

```
 <div ng-include src="'/home/projects/test2.html'"></div>
```

It is working

**Case2:** , but why I need to give whole path, So I tried the following, but it not working.

```
 <div ng-include src="'test2.html'"></div>
```

One more think, I have created [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), for projects's parent directory, which is **front-end**
So basically **home** point home -> ../../front-end/

Inside front-end **projects** directory is available, where test1.html and test2.html are reside.

So please tell me why case 2 is not working, If both are in same directory..

Comment: consider you app start from index.htm page. so it match from brower url. so share your browser url. point relative path from url

Answer (score -3):

just remove single quotes from file name in `src` attribute. I think it will work.

Do write like given below:

`src="test2.html"`

Comment: no, it won't...... ng-include 's src has to be given like that..... check your answer before providing it....or get downvoted

Comment: @Avjeet Ghosh: I have tested both ways and then only i have suggested it.